# R - converting multiple xtabs to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, lapply, contingency

R version 3.3.2

I am trying to obtain a single data frame from a list of xtabs. So far, I've managed to combine the multiple xtabs, but I haven't been successful in converting that to a data frame. Moreover, I would like to know if it's possible to include the dimnames of the xtabs in said data frame, separating the different xtabs.

Here is a reproductible example:

```
id <- c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID6", "ID7", "ID8", "ID9", "ID10", "ID11", "ID12", "ID13", "ID14", "ID15")
outcome <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, "FP", 0, 1, 1, "FP", 0, 1, "FP", 0, 1)
question1 <- c("No", "No", "Sometimes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Sometimes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No")
question2 <- c("NYC", "LA", "LA", "NYC", "NYC", "NYC", "NYC", "NYC", "NYC", "LA", "NYC", "NYC", "NYC", "NYC", "NYC")
question3 <- c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No")
question4 <- c("Nurse", "Neurologist", "Oncologist", "Internist", "Nurse", "Neurologist", "Nurse", "Nurse", "Oncologist", "Nurse", "Nurse", "Internist", "Nurse", "Neurologist", "Nurse")
question5 <- c("Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male")
question6 <- c(42, 35, 39, 32, 40, 51, 37, 42, 33, 41, 55, 53, 45, 38, 52)

df <- data.frame(id, outcome, question1, question2, question3, question4, question5, question6)
```

In order to obtain the list of contingency tables I wrote the following:

```
bar <- lapply(colnames(subset(df, select = -c(id, outcome))),

              function(var) {

                  formula <- as.formula(paste("~", var, "+ outcome"))

                  xtabs(formula, data = df)
              })
```

Then, in order to obtain a data frame from that list, I used ldply:

```
ldply(colnames(subset(df, select = -c(id, outcome))),

      function(var) {

        formula <- as.formula(paste("~", var, "+ outcome"))

        xtabs(formula, data = df)
      })
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work for me since I lose the names of the variables in the process.
I then tried binding the elements of the list and converting that to a data frame with:

```
bar2 <- bar[[1]]
lapply(2:length(bar), function(i) {bar2 <<- rbind(bar2, bar[[i]])})
data.frame(bar2)
```

Two problems arise: I get a warning message and lose the names of the variables again and I still can't find a way to include the dimnames between the answers (row variables). I would like for my final data frame to look something like this:

```
            outcome 

            0 1 FP
question1
No          1 3  1
Sometimes   0 2  0
Yes         3 3  2
question2
LA          0 2  1
NYC         4 6  2
question3
No          2 4  2
Yes         2 4  1
question4
Internist   0 2  0
Neurologist 1 1  1
Nurse       3 3  2
Oncologist  0 2  0
question5
Female      0 4  2
Male        4 4  1
question6
32          0 1  0
33          0 1  0
35          0 1  0
37          1 0  0
38          1 0  0
39          0 1  0
40          1 0  0
41          0 0  1
42          0 2  0
45          0 0  1
51          0 0  1
52          0 1  0
53          0 1  0
55          1 0  0
```

I tried numerous ways and read all I could find, but I can't find a way to make it work, especially when it comes to accessing the dimnames (i.e. 'outcome', 'question1', 'question2', etc.). Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does `do.call(rbind, lapply(names(df)[-(1:2)], function(x) table(df[[x]], df$outcome) ))` do what you want?

Comment: Your desired result is not a dataframe but more a report. Dataframes are lists of equal length atomic vectors where each column is same type within but different between. Here you have mixed types and gaps, repeating headers, etc. Consider text or spreadsheet output for your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer! It does solve part of my problems @thelatemail

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Parfait! I'm sorry, but could you please explain what do you mean by text or spreadsheet output (I'm still not very experienced in R) - do you mean manually inserting the headers? Thanks in advance for your help!